# How to mock fetch in custom hook with Mock Service Worker?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, msw

I want to test my application that has a user input a query that sends a request to the Google Books API, then the response is displayed.

I've separated the data fetching logic into its own custom hook. I want to mock the fetch with Mock Service Worker. I'm receiving an invalid hook call when I run my test.

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      3 |
      4 | export const useBooksFetch = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
    > 5 |   const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
        |                         ^
      6 |   const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
      7 |   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
      8 |   const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

      at resolveDispatcher (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1476:13)
      at useState (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1507:20)
      at useBooksFetch (src/hooks/useBooksFetch/useBooksFetch.js:5:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hooks/useBooksFetch/useBooksFetch.test.js:78:24)

  console.warn
    [MSW] Found a redundant usage of query parameters in the request handler URL for "GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=travel". Please match against a path instead, and access query parameters in the response resolver function:
    
    rest.get("/books/v1/volumes", (req, res, ctx) => {
      const query = req.url.searchParams
      const q = query.get("q")
    })      

      4 |
      5 | const server = setupServer(
    > 6 |   rest.get(
        |        ^
      7 |     "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=travel",
      8 |     (req, res, ctx) => {
      9 |       return res(
```

Confirmations

- Confirmed matching React versions when running `npm ls react-dom` and `npm ls react`, and returned `react-dom@17.0.2` and `react@17.0.2`.
- Not being called within class component, event-handler, useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect.

What am I doing wrong? [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1-google-books-usestate-wnvbs?file=/src/components/Loader/index.js)

```
// useBooksFetch.js
export const useBooksFetch = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBooks = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios(url);
        setData(result.data);
      } catch (isError) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchBooks();
  }, [url]);

  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, setUrl];
};


// useBooksFetch.test.js
const server = setupServer(
  rest.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=travel",
    (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(
        ctx.status(200),
        ctx.json({
          data: {
            items: [
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "Travels"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "The Travel Book"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "Two Arabic Travel Books"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "Around India in 80 Trains"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "World Travel"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title:
                    "The ‘Book’ of Travels: Genre, Ethnology, and Pilgrimage, 1250-1700"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "The Impossible Collection of Chinese Art"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "Travel Home"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "Maximum City"
                }
              },
              {
                volumeInfo: {
                  title: "The Art of Travel"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        })
      );
    }
  )
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterAll(() => server.close());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());

it("fetches successfully", async () => {
  const result = await useBooksFetch();
  expect(result.data).toHaveLength(10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is right, u can't use hooks outside of the component.

Use for example this library https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library